# Reliable options to get from Rome Ciampino to Civitavecchia?

Tags: italy, cruising

I'm looking to get to Civitavecchia port from Ciampino for a cruise in September. I know there are public transport options (bus and train), but I have 3 other people to bring and a load of luggage. Can anyone recommend either a reliable shuttle bus or taxi company and the costs? The main thing for me is reliability as I've been let down in Italy before with cab bookings online. Many thanks for your advice.

Comment: I think you should check the website of your cruise. Possibly they will organize something (probably for a fee). Civitavecchia is one of the worse ports in the world for managing tourists, and one of the most expensive (see e.g. cruisecritic website).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Port of [Civitavecchia web site](http://www.civitavecchiaport.org/how-to-get-there/) has details of the various ways to get to the port, including transfers from airports (FCO and Ciampino). It also has an [authorized car transfer service](http://www.civitavecchiaport.org/transfer/) which has top ratings on Trip Advisor. An arbitrary search to take four passengers from Ciampino to the port in mid-September, one way, was priced at €130; round trip would be €260.

Disclaimer: I have no affiliation, but have used similar, private car hire services for Rome airport transfers, which are €100 one way.